# whenever gem crashes Rails console method autocompletion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, whenever

Since I upgraded to Rails 7, when I type dot after variable name in my rails console, it often crashes with the error below.

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/whenever-1.0.0/lib/whenever/job_list.rb:41:in `respond_to?': undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
                 when
      @set_variables.has_key?(name) || super
                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

I can see that it caused by whenever gem, but how to I fix this? The method autocomplete feature is so nice, but it crashes so easily such that the console is unusable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a bug in the `whenever` code. For now, either don't require it in the `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'whenever', require: false
```

Either use a hack: https://gist.github.com/hirogeek/1c6d511a77ec3b15dea8a0db0a11fb1c

Comment: Thanks. Only if I just RTFM.. (the manual states `require: false`)